# how we launch Activity from fragments

Tags: java, android

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(i);
```

I want to go from fragment to `Activity` by using the `seOnClickListener`.
Above code is not working

Comment: Because a Fragment doesn't have its own context (`this`).

Comment: `It's not working` it's not an explanation. Check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityTwo.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(FragmentName.this.getActivity(), ActivityTwo.class);
FragmentName.this.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Fragments do not have *startActivity* method

Comment: Yes, I was refactor answer.
@JonZarate

Comment: You didn't make any relevant change. It is still wrong.

Comment: @JonZarate
I added getActivity().

Comment: You still haven't fixed your code. ** Fragments do not have startActivity method**. I already told you. Try your code in an IDE before posting it.

Comment: Please check, Fragment from the package android.support.v4.app;
It has startActivity and startActivityForResult methods.
@JonZarate

Comment: He is not using `android.support.v4`. If he was, his code would work.

Comment: His code don't worked because, he try to call startActivity from the implemetation setOnClickListener(), this impl is anon class, and has diff context between fragment. 
And in this case we must use, Fragment.class.this

Comment: False. You can use `startActivity()` in `android.support.v4` inside `View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)`. I told you to **try your code** before posting.

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityTwo.class);
 getActivity.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
In your fragment write below code.

private Activity mActivity;

@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mActivity = (Activity) context;
    }

and then call your activity

Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, ActivityTwo.class);
mActivity.startActivity(intent);

this will work for you.
```

Comment: Why do I have to save an `Activity` instance if I can `getActivity()`? Your member `mActivity` is not necessary.

Comment: getActivity() may be null and it always better to attach your fragments to activity.

Comment: `getActivity() may be null`. False. I won't believe that if you do not provide any source that says so. That would be an Android bug, and I doubt it is.

Comment: It's not about your believe...sometimes in fabric crash analytics tool gives getActivity() == null it's always better to go for onAttach().It's not android bug.

Comment: Your code doesn't proof there is a bug in Android OS. You must have called `getActivity()` when you shouldn't.